# Filtering data with Firebase (firestore) and Angular 5

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5, angularfire5

I am struggling to find good material on best practices for filtering data using firebase firestore, angularfire5 and angular 5. I am building a map based web app, similar to a real estate app. And I have pins on the map that need to be filtered by different attributes. Do you know of any good articles I can read? Or how this should be best approached.

Some questions that come to mind are:

- Client side filtering vs query based filtering?
- What is a good way to store data in firestore that assists with filtering?

**Example object data:**

```js
{
  "key": {
    "suburb": "Chelsea",
    "lng": 90,
    "lat": -90,
    "street": "Lennox",
    "streetNo": 200,
    "lotSize": 600,
    "city": "langdon",
    "attributeKeys": [
      {
        "key1": true,
        "key2": true,
        "key3": true,
        "key4": false,
        "key5": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Let's assume the following filter scenario: All map items in chelsea, lot size greater than 400, where key1 = true and key2 = true.

Below is an example of my current service:

```
this.mapItems = Observable.combineLatest(
  this.suburb,
  this.minLotSize,
  this.maxLotSize,
  this.attrbute1Filter,
).switchMap(([suburb, minLotSize, maxLotSize, attrbute1Filter]) =>
  afs.collection('properties', ref => {
    let query: any = ref;
    if (suburb) { query = query.where('address.suburb', '==', suburb) };
    if (minLotSize) { query = query.where('attributes.lotArea', '>=', minLotSize) };
    if (maxLotSize) { query = query.where('attributes.lotArea', '<=', maxLotSize) };
    if (attrbute1Filter) { query = query.where('attributeKeys.key1', '==', subdivisionFilter) }
    return query;
  })
    .valueChanges()
  );
```

Thanks for your help.